# head command - find first line of non-whitespace

Tags: node.js, file, utf-8, fs, head

Is there a way to use the head command to find the first line of a file that contains non-whitespace? It would be too kludgy just read the first 100 lines and hope that one of them has non-whitespace.

It doesn't have to be with the head command - all I am looking for is a very performant way to avoid reading the whole file and just getting the first line that matches non-whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with simple `grep` and a regular expression

```
grep -m 1 -E "\S+" /path/to/file
```

The `\S+` will match any non-whitespace characters, and with `-m 1` we will stop after the first match.

Comment: Ok but won't grep go through the whole file? Can I tell grep to stop after the first or second match?

Comment: Edited. Just add `-m 1` ;)

Comment: Good call, this actually eliminated the need for _head_ too.